# Database for testing and public database. How to use both?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

Currently I have my project connected to the database placed on Windows Azure, but I will be soon publishing my website for other people. When I'm making changes to my site, I often make changes to the database too. So during my work on my site, public webpage will not work.

How can I create local database which will be used locally, while testing and how can I automatically switch to this public db when my project is in Internet?

I use Asp.Net MVC5 with Entity Framework.

Comment: How about using different connection strings for test and production databases?

Comment: @Sergey but how to specify which one should be used locally and which on internet? And how can I get connectionString to the local db (which btw currently doesn't exsist)?

Answer (score 2):

This is what Configurations are for in Visual Studio. You put your development connection string in your Web.config for development, and then in Web.Release.config, for example, you add a transform to change that connection string to the production version. Then, when you publish the site, you select the appropriate configuration, "Release" in this example, and the published Web.config will contain the production connection string. More information on configurations and using Web.config transforms can be found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. But, do I have to do something to generate this local database? I set the connection string and I got this error: "Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\[...]\App_Data\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection'.". I thought that it will be automiatically generated, but it isn't